# Identifier for a long function in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I use PL/SQL developer and I wrote long "equation" in SELECT, where are also use functions. This equation I also need to use in another part of my script. It looks like

```
SELECT t.something1,
       ROUND((SYSDATE - 1 + 2),1) AS NAME
FROM customers t
WHERE t.something1 = ROUND((SYSDATE - 1 + 2),1)
```

My question is: is it possible to make something like identifier for `ROUND((SYSDATE - 1 + 2),1)` to avoid using this long line also in WHERE?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split it into two SELECTs:

```
select v1.* from (
  SELECT 
    t.something1,
    ROUND((SYSDATE - 1 + 2),1) AS NAME
  FROM customers t
) v1
WHERE v1.something1 = v1.name
```

Comment: It looks really nice and it should solve my problem. But isn't there  anything like FROM customers t and than you use just t?